# Mockito Stubbing

Tags: junit, mockito

Listed below is a method I am trying to test using Junit and Mockito

Java Code

```
public String getAuthenticationService() {
        Authentication endpoint;
        String token = "";

        try {
            URL wsdlURL = new URL(authenticationURL);
            SoapService service = new SoapService(wsdlURL,
                    new QName("SomeQName",
                            "SoapService"));

            endpoint = service.getAuthenticationPort();

            token = endpoint.authenticate(username, password);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new GenericException(
                    "OpenText AuthenticationService not working Error is "
                            + e.toString());
        }
        return token;
    }
```

Junit method

```
public void testGetAuthenticationService()
            throws AuthenticationException_Exception {

        AuthenticationService mockService = Mockito
                .mock(AuthenticationService.class);

        Authentication mockEndpoint = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);

        Mockito.when(mockService.getAuthenticationPort()).thenReturn(
                mockEndpoint);

        Mockito.when(mockEndpoint.authenticate(username, password)).thenReturn(
                token);
}
```

When I run the Junit test case the endpoint.authenticate tries to connect to the actaul soap service, and the method stubbing is not working, what am I doing wrong here

Comment: Alternative approach - mock the actual service on localhost: https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mockService` seems to be a good replacement for your `SoapService`, but you aren't giving yourself an opportunity to *refer* to it in your code. Your test calls the code, which calls the SoapService constructor, so you get a real service. Consider this refactor:

```
public String getAuthenticationService() {
    try {
        URL wsdlURL = new URL(authenticationURL);
        SoapService service = new SoapService(wsdlURL,
            new QName("SomeQName", "SoapService"));

        return getAuthenticationService(service);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new GenericException(
                "OpenText AuthenticationService not working Error is "
                        + e.toString());
    }
}

/** package-private for testing - call this from your test instead */
String getAuthenticationService(AuthenticationService service) {
    try {
        Authentication endpoint = service.getAuthenticationPort();
        String token = endpoint.authenticate(username, password);
           return token;    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new GenericException(
                "OpenText AuthenticationService not working Error is "
                            + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Now you can pass your `mockService` into `getAuthenticationService(service)` and your code will use your mock rather than the `SoapService` it creates inline.

As as alternative, you can also give yourself a seam by wrapping the SoapService constructor:

```
/** overridden in tests */
protected AuthenticationService createSoapService(String url, QName qname) {
    return new SoapService(url, qname);
}

public String getAuthenticationService() {
    try {
        URL wsdlURL = new URL(authenticationURL);
        SoapService service = createSoapService(wsdlURL,
            new QName("SomeQName", "SoapService"));

        Authentication endpoint = service.getAuthenticationPort();
        String token = endpoint.authenticate(username, password);
           return token;    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new GenericException(
                "OpenText AuthenticationService not working Error is "
                            + e.toString());
    }
}

// in your test:

SystemUnderTest yourSystem = new YourSystem() {
  @Override protected AuthenticationService createAuthenticationService(
      String url, QName qname) {
    return mockService;
  }
}
```